# Average rank of elliptic curves over one-parameter family

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E_t:y^2=x^3+f(t)x+g(t)$ be an one parameter family of elliptic curves with $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$. I found one Silverman's result https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1998.109/pdf that asserts that the average rank of the family $\{E_t, t\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is bounded, under GRH and BSD. Is there any progress on this ever since? what is known unconditionally?